# Creating polygon from leased unit metes and bounds calls using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, references, parcel, boundaries, metes-and-bounds

I have a dataset containing with metes and bounds listing an area.
I want to build a layer from these calls and produce the lines (polygons) that show the area.

I know there may be a bit of inaccuracy due to ground based measurements, etc., but I have to start somewhere so I am looking for a process to create the layer and begin to build lines based on bearing and range, mostly.

I tried in ArcMap 10.6 to create a line layer in a Geodatabase, but I am guessing I need to create certain fields to make this work and I do not know what fields to start with.

**Overall**, what I am ASKING for is a simple tutorial that will start with nothing but an empty map, and allow a layer to be created and populated with lines, (or polygons,) based on inputs like this:

S 09-32 W 387.9 feet
S 61-40 E 275.1

One call appears to describe a curve:

> "S 20-14 E 9002.0 feet, with a curve to the left having a Radius of
>   832.6 feet, an ARC length of 888.3 feet, a Chord length of 846.8 feet, and a Chord bearing of S 17-35 E to the Point of Beginning"

Be aware that there are many tutorials about this sort of thing, but I have not found one that will take me from nothing to the end, without making assumptions that other parcels or polygons are already created in a layer, or that a Geodatabase already properly exists.

Comment: I think that this is too broad for focussed Q&A because it is asking for a tutorial to be provided/written.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather broad question, so I'm not going into too much detail here. These instruction assume ArcMap, not ArcGIS Pro.

**Create a polygon feature class**

1. In ArcMap, open the *Catalog* window (Windows → Catalog)
2. In the Catalog Window, browse to the location where you want to store the data; click right: New → File Geodatabase. You may have to connect a folder first: Click on the *Connect To Folder* button on the Catalog Window's toolbar to do that.
3. Right click on the geodatabase you just created: New → Feature Class
4. Enter a name, and the type (Polygon Features)
5. Next: Select the spatial reference you want to use
6. Next; Next; Enter any additional fields; Finish

The feature class will be added to the map automatically. Optionally, you could add reference data such as imagery or a topographical map: File → Add Data → Add basemap

**Edit the featureclass**

1. Right click on the layer in the table of contents: Edit Features → Organize Feature Templates; New Template; Select All; Finish
2. Right click on the layer in the table of contents: Edit Features → Start Editing
3. Open the Editor toolbar, if it's not open yet: Customize → Toolbars → Editor
4. From the Editor Toolbar, open the *Create Features* Window: Editor → Editing Windows → Create Features
5. In the Create Features window, select the polygon class (top) and the Polygon Construction Tool (bottom)
6. Draw a line by clicking on each corner, and double click to finish
7. Repeat. Finally, save your edits: Editor → Stop Editing

Here's the [complete reference](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing/what-is-editing-.htm).

**Advanced line drawing**

- To start a line on a known coordinate, right click on the map and select *Absolute X, Y* (Or press <kbd>F6</kbd>)
- To create a line with a specific length or direction, start a line, then click right and select *Direction/Length* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>), *Direction* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) or *Length* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)
- To create a curve with specific parameters, use the *End Point Arc Segment* tool on the editor toolbar, rather than *Straight Segment*. While drawing, press <kbd>R</kbd> to specify a radius

You might also want to try the other options in the context menu, and tools on the Advanced Editing toolbar.

[COGO](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/an-overview-of-cogo.htm) might also be of interest for you, but since I have never used it myself, I can't offer any help there.